# Find RegExp and Replace specific character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find a numeric value + quotes within a string (example 5"). Once found, I need to replace the quote with "pound". Unfortunately, the string is complex:
Sample string

```
Work and run with Joe "The King" Mel using a 3" vest with "Dog-Bone" weights.
```

I have tried

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('Work and run with Joe "The King" Mel using a 3" vest with "Dog-Bone" weights.', '%[^0-9]"%', 'pound'), '"', 'pound')
```

But it replaces all the quotes with 'pound'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will find the first occurrence of a number followed by a `"` and replace `"` with  `pound`.

```
declare @s varchar(100) 
set @s = 'Work and run with Joe "The King" Mel using a 3" vest with "Dog-Bone" weights.'
select stuff(@s, patindex('%[0-9]"%', @s)+1, 1, ' pound')
```

[STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

[PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

If you have more than one you can put it in a while loop.

```
while patindex('%[0-9]"%', @s) > 0
begin
  set @s = stuff(@s, patindex('%[0-9]"%', @s)+1, 1, ' pound')
end
```

Comment: works great ... WHILE corrected some errors with PATINDEX default value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't express a deterministic algorithm for the change you want to make, you'll never be able to write a regular expression as an implementation.

You'd written two replace expressions: one replaces only quotes after numbers, but the other replaces all the quotes, period.

Comment: I am trying code to find the position of quote contained in the regexp '%[^0-9]"% and then doing a replace on that specific char position. But not working ..

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a CLR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx